# Phasor transform of a constant value?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Let's say I have the KVL of an RC circuit:

$$v_s = R~i + v(0) + \frac{1}{C} \int \limits_{0}^{t} i(\tau) d\tau$$

I take the phasor transform of both sides of this equation...much like a laplace transform:

$$P\bigg\{v_s \bigg\} = P\bigg\{R~i + v(0) + \frac{1}{C} \int \limits_{0}^{t} i(\tau) d\tau \bigg\}$$

I get:

$$V_s = RI + P\bigg\{v(0)\bigg\} + \frac{1}{C}\frac{1}{j\omega}I$$

but what's the phasor transform of a constant?

$$P\bigg\{v(0)\bigg\} = ?$$

Comment: Usually when you use phasors it is for AC analysis only, and you consider only AC steady state conditions (after all transient response has settled out). This means that you would ignore the voltage on the cap at t=0. Or, assume the voltage is 0 and phase angle is 0.

Comment: what do the X & Y axes represent ? X+jY

Comment: phasor transform converts a real number sinusoid into complex number domain exponential function according to euler identity..  $$A cos(\omega t+\phi) = Re\{A e^{j\omega + j\phi}\}$$... the phasor transform is a bit like going inside of the brackets of $$Re\{ \}$$  to do all the calculations..that's why everything is complex numbers with phasors...then convert back to real numbers in the end to get a physical representation of the voltage or current again in real numbers...

Comment: they just drop the $$e^{j\omega}$$ portion in phasor form as a convenience because its a lot of trouble to keep writing it when you could just factor it out since everything is in steady state and has the same angular frequency.

Comment: I think Tony's question was rhetorical. He was suggesting that you think about what a constant voltage would look like in the phasor domain. Having said that, consider mkeith's comment...phasors are generally used for ac steady-state analysis and the initial capacitor voltage would not be relevant.